# Is there a way to simplify a save/update module?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm coding an application that has several tables and fields that, of course, need to be saved and updated. Each section, say, a page, has its own module that has save/update/remove subs.

This is an example of a save sub inside a save module:

```
Public Sub saveRecToStaff(FirstName As String, LastName As String, Address As String, Email As String, PhoneNumber As String, Status As String)
Dim rstSave As New ADODB.Recordset
rstSave.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rstSave.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rstSave.LockType = adLockOptimistic

rstSave.Open "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, PhoneNumber, Status FROM Staff"
rstSave.addNew

rstSave.Fields("FirstName").Value = FirstName
rstSave.Fields("LastName").Value = LastName
rstSave.Fields("Address").Value = Address
rstSave.Fields("Email").Value = Email
rstSave.Fields("PhoneNumber").Value = PhoneNumber
rstSave.Fields("Status").Value = Status
rstSave.update

rstSave.Close
Set rstSave = Nothing
End Sub
```

For a while now, I've been thinking that maybe there could be a way to simplify this procedure. For example, creating a base function that is simply called whenever there is a need to save. I'm very new with VBA coding, however, so I'm not sure how I should go about this.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: What about an update sequence?

```
Public Sub saveRecToStaff(oldFirstName As String, FirstName As String, oldLastName As String,
LastName As String, oldAddress As String, Address As String, Email As String, PhoneNumber As String,
 Status As String)
Dim rstSave As New ADODB.Recordset
rstSave.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rstSave.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rstSave.LockType = adLockOptimistic

rstUpdate.Open "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, PhoneNumber, Status FROM Staff 
 WHERE FirstName='"& oldFirstName & "' AND LastName='" & oldLastName & "' AND Address='" & oldAddress & "'"

If (rstUpdate.EOF = False) Then
rstUpdate.update
rstUpdate.Fields("FirstName").Value = FirstName
rstUpdate.Fields("LastName").Value = LastName
rstUpdate.Fields("Address").Value = Address
rstUpdate.Fields("Email").Value = Email
rstUpdate.Fields("PhoneNumber").Value = PhoneNumber
rstUpdate.Fields("Status").Value = Status
rstUpdate.update
End If

rstSave.Close
Set rstSave = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use shorter/simpler code by switching to DAO. By using `With`, the recordset doesn't need to be declared and auto-closes:

```
Public Sub saveRecToStaff(FirstName As String, LastName As String, Address As String, Email As String, PhoneNumber As String, Status As String)
    With CurrentDb.TableDefs!Staff.OpenRecordset
        .AddNew
        .Fields("FirstName").Value = FirstName
        .Fields("LastName").Value = LastName
        .Fields("Address").Value = Address
        .Fields("Email").Value = Email
        .Fields("PhoneNumber").Value = PhoneNumber
        .Fields("Status").Value = Status
        .Update
    End With
End Sub
```

However, you could use a bound form too, and then you wouldn't need to use any VBA to add new rows. You could only use the built-in form functionality.

Comment: Very cleaver.  You should probably mention the use of brackets `[]` when the table name is not valid variable name. `With CurrentDb.TableDefs![Wait Staff].OpenRecordset`. +1 ∞

Comment: Nice, thank you! I will use this in the future. I added an edit about an update sequence, can it be handled in the same way? Also, do you think that this is a legit way to handle save sequences, or would queries be more beneficial?

Comment: @veckorevyn That's a very different question. Your current code there is wide open to SQL injection and associated bugs (try to update a name to O'Connel, for example). For updates, I really recommend using bound forms. Also, that code doesn't really makes sense, because you're filtering on the same thing you're updating to.